# ¿Cómo hago una busqueda en una linkedlist de java tomando de parametro un nombre?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda en una linkedlist de automoviles, por decirlo así, considerando como parámetro de búsqueda el nombre de los autos. Se que en una linkedList de puros enteros basta poner de argumento como esta en el siguiente método

```
public class BusquedaLineal {
boolean check;
public boolean BuscarClave(List<Integer> lista, int clave){
    for(int i=0; i<lista.size() ;i++){
        if(lista.get(i)==clave){
            check=true;
            return check;
        }
    }
    check = false;
    return check;
}
```

Ahora, tengo una clase que define el tipo de dato "automovil":

```
public class Automovil {
 //Atributos
 String nombre, color, marca;
 int modelo;

 Automovil(String n, String c, String mark, Integer m) {
   nombre = n;
   color = c;
   marca = mark;
   modelo = m;
 }

 public String toString() {
  return nombre + " " + color + " " + marca + " " + modelo;
 }
}
```

Mi clase principal con los "automoviles" es esta:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args){
LinkedList<Automovil> autos = new LinkedList<Automovil>();

    autos.add(new Automovil("Logan", "Negro", "Renault", 2016));
    autos.add(new Automovil("Versa", "Gris", "Nissan", 2014));
    autos.add(new Automovil("Matrix", "Rojo", "Toyota", 2006));

    for (Automovil element : autos)
        System.out.println(element + "\n");
    
}
```

La duda es, ¿cómo hago una búsqueda por nombre utilizando mi método de búsqueda lineal?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean buscarClave(List<Automovil> lista, String clave){

  for(Automovil automovil : lista){
    // obtener el nombre del automovil para 
    // compararlo con la clave si coincide retornar verdadero
    if(automovil.getNombre().equals(clave)) return true;
  }
  // si no se encontró retornar falso
  return false;
}
```